# How to Convert NSValue to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationcoordinate2d

How to convert `NSValue` to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`?

I receive `NSValue` in `(NSArray *)coordinateArray` and need to get `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for each `NSValue` in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Obj-C**

```
#import <MapKit/MKGeometry.h> 

NSValue *coordinateValue; 
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [coordinateValue MKCoordinateValue];
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
let coordinateValue: NSValue = NSValue.init()
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = coordinateValue.mkCoordinateValue
```